# A school would like a private channel to post videos accessable by login or QR code only

Tags: youtube-api

I am working with a school who would like to post some videos but do to privacy issues do not want them visible unless someone with the access to the QR codes scans one. Is there an option for a private channel like that?

Comment: You can make a video private and share it with people via Google+ integration, a circle can be given access - or you can just keep it unlisted and make the link private.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=en-GB

Comment: Specifically what you are after isn't directly available.  Though you could make the QR code a link to the unlisted link.